# Adding delegate in C#

Tags: c#, f#, delegates

How does one add a new function to a delegate without using the += notation ?

I wonder how to do his from another CLR langage, namely F#. (I know there are much nicer way to deal with events in F#, but I am being curious..)

```
static int Square (int x) { return x * x; }
static int Cube(int x) { return x * x * x; }
delegate int Transformer (int x);

Transformer d = Square ;
d += Cube;
```

**Edit**

As pointed out by Daniel in the comments, the fact that one has no direct way of doing this probably is a design decision by dotnet team to not mutate the queue too much.

Comment: do you want answer in `F#` ?

Comment: why not, at least without += syntactic sugar

Comment: just, you're question has a C# in the title

Comment: F# equivalent of `d += Cube;` will be `d.Add(Cube)`

Comment: d.invoke() invokes method

Comment: @vishalsharma A method is not a .net delegate.  That's why you would have to do `d.Add(Cube)`.  The `Add` method creates a delegate from the `Cube` method.

Comment: @mydogisbox i think nocolas talks about an alternative way to invoke  method using delegate .. so Transformer is delegate and to invoke  methodu have to use delegate.invoke....

Comment: @AppDeveloper , mydogisbox except there is no such add method on Action

Comment: F# shuns destructive updates of delegate lists. `Event<_>` works the same way.

Comment: This question is about normal delegates, not event handlers. Why do you think it is a duplicate? I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to do it in F#. You need downcasting due to the use of [Delegate.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30cyx32c.aspx):

```ml
let square x = x * x
let cube x = x * x * x

type Transformer = delegate of int -> int

let inline (++) (a: 'T) (b: 'T) = 
    System.Delegate.Combine(a, b) :?> 'T

let d = Transformer(square)
let e = d ++ Transformer(cube)
```

Comment: yes that is the only thing I saw. the advantage of this writing is that is provides type safety, which we have to provide ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

Delegate.Combine?

```
d = (Transformer) Delegate.Combine(d, new Transformer(Cube));
```

Comment: indeed. only way.. now to wrap that in a type safe way, cf pad's answer.